# How to sum variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to make the following:
[image]

I m tryng to sum the 3 products and show in total field, but with onchange event. When i select the first combobox, save the value in total, with the second combobox the same things, sum the value with total but dont work for me. What can i do?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
$('select#cant1').on('change',function(){
    var valor1 = '1500' * $(this).val();
    $("#valProd1").text(valor1);
});

$('select#cant2').on('change',function(){
    var valor2 = '220000' * $(this).val();
    $("#valProd2").text(valor2);
});

$('select#cant3').on('change',function(){
    var valor3 = '1300' * $(this).val();
    $("#valProd3").text(valor3);
});

$('select#cant1,cant2').on('change',function(){
    var op = $("#cant1");
    var op1 = op * 1500;
    $("#valSubtotal").text(op1);
});
});
```

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patriciodilet/RGdU2)

Comment: Use `parseInt()` on all your variables, currently you're trying to multiply two strings together

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for it?

Comment: also `'1500'` is not the same as `1500`. You need to remove the quotes

Comment: Yes! here is http://jsfiddle.net/patriciodilet/RGdU2/ thanks!

Comment: This made me think of [the jQuery arithmetic plugin joke](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Answer (score 1):

add a class named `valor` for your each select then

```
$('.valor').on('change',function(){

 var valor1 = 1500 * $("#cant1").val();
 var valor2 = 220000 * $("#cant2").val();
 var valor3 = 1300 * $("#cant3").val();

 $("#valProd1").text(valor1);
 $("#valProd2").text(valor2);
 $("#valProd3").text(valor3);


 $("#valSubtotal").text(valor1 + valor2  + valor3);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RGdU2/4

Comment: @scrowler i dont test but i think not necessary, ill check

Answer (score 0):

The following should work fine:

```
var valor1 = 1500 * +$(this).val();
```

Instead of:

```
var valor1 = '1500' * $(this).val();
```

The `+` works more or less like `parseInt()`, and you do not want to quote numbers otherwise you would need to cast them too.

A function such as the following can be called withing each change callback so the total is updated each time a drop down is changed:

```
function total() {
    $('#valTotal').text( +$('#valProd3').text().trim() + +$('#valProd2').text().trim() + +$('#valProd1').text().trim() );
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RGdU2/3/)

Comment: Thanks! but my problem is that i dont can to sum the 3 products, dont work or i dont know how to resolve this

Comment: What are you adding to what to what? You can do a simple `sum` like this: `var total = +$('$cant1').val() + +$('#cant2').val() + +$('#cant3').val()`

Comment: i want to sum 3 products in total field

Comment: exactly! but when i change any combobox show this sum in total. But dont work.. i put this (your example) and no...

Comment: Please take a look at the `function` and demo I have added to my answer.